# What is wrong with this Regex in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I've written a regex to help validate a String for game character names. It's somehow passing seemingly invalid strings and not passing seemingly valid strings.

Requirements:

- Starts with a capital letter
- Has any number of alphanumeric characters after that (this includes spaces)

This is the rails code that does the validation in the Character Model:

`validates :name, format: { with: %r{[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*} }`

Here's the unit test I'm using

```
test "character name should be properly formatted and does not contain any special characters" do
    character = get_valid_character
    assert character.valid?

    character.name = "aBcd"
    assert character.invalid?, "#{character.name} should be invalid"

    character.name = "Number 1"
    assert character.valid?, "#{character.name} should be valid"

    character.name = "McDonalds"
    assert character.valid?, "#{character.name} should be valid"

    character.name = "Abcd."
    assert character.invalid?, "#{character.name} should be invalid"

    character.name = "Abcd%"
    assert character.invalid?, "#{character.name} should be invalid"
end
```

The problems:
The regex passes "aBcd", "Abcd.", and "Abcd%" when it shouldn't. Now, I know this works because I tested this out in Python and it works just as you would expect.

What gives?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular expressions look for matches anywhere in the given string unless told otherwise.

So the test string `'aBcd'` is invalid, but it contains a valid substring: `'Bcd'`. Same with `'Abcd%'`, where the valid substring is `'Abcd'`.

If you want to match the entire string, use this as your regex:

```
# \A matches string beginning, \z matches string end
%r{\A[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*\z}
```

PS: Some people will say to match the beginning of a string with `^` and the end with `$`. In Ruby, those symbols match the beginning and end of a *line*, not a string. So `"ABCD\n%"` would still match if you used `^` and `$`, but won't match if you use `\A` and `\z`. See the [Rails security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions) for more on this.

Comment: Would that properly forbid newlines? Some Google-hits suggest that in Ruby, `^` and `$` default to meaning "start-of-line" and "end-of-line" (like other languages' multiline-mode regexes), so you need to use `\A` and `\z` to mean "start-of-string" and "end-of-string". (I have not tested this myself.)

Comment: Rushing to get the answer, and I forgot about that gotcha. :)

Comment: Thank you that clears this up a lot! It works wonderfully now!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match the capital letter at the beginning of the string, you need to put in the "start of line" marker `^` so it would look like:

```
validates :name, format: { with: %r{^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*} }
```

Check out [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to play around with your regex

Comment: Rubular is actually where I tested the answer to this question. :) Great resource.

Comment: No problem. so close though, but Jergason's is exactly what you need. Good luck!